# Extracting fields of lines in a text file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

How can I extract the third value and all subsequent ones
(i.e., discard the first two values)
from each line in a text file containing, for example, the following values?

```
1 1112 0 1 2
2 1111 0 2
3 1211 1 0 3
```

I want to ignore `1 1112`, `2 1111`, and `3 1211` and get only the values

```
0 1 2
0 2
1 0 3
```

all of which belong to what I call the third group of values for every line.

Comment: Is it always skipping the first two number groups? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What's the formula? `echo 0 1 2` could be an Answer at this point.

Comment: Sorry let me elaborate. As @John said i am skipping two number groups and fetching the third group of numbers. It is not just this one line it could be multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple table format, what I can sugest is to use `cut` command and remove the first two columns delimited by space.

```
$ echo "01 1112 0 1 2" | cut -d " " -f 3-
```

Using this with a file:

```
$ cut -d " " -f 3- file.txt > output_expected.txt
```

**Give a try**

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a regex approach:

```
$ sed -r 's/^(.[^ ]* ){2}//g' <<<$'1 1112 0 1 2\n2 1111 0 2\n3 1211 1 0 3'
0 1 2
0 2
1 0 3
```